# How to do operations on specific columns using pandas python Part 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following two dataframes and I would like to create a third df3 dataframe:

df1

```
  Monday_One     Monday_Two Tuesday
       Water          Water     Ice
        Cold Hot        Hot    Cold
0          4   1          1      10
1          5   2          2       9
2          6   3          7       8
3          7   3          4       7
4          8   5          5       6
```

df2

```
   Area         
  Water      Ice
   Cold Hot Cold
0     4   1   10
1     5   2    9
2     6   3    8
3     7   4    7
4     8   5    6
```

df3

```
  Monday_One     Monday_Two Tuesday
       Water          Water     Ice
        Cold Hot        Hot    Cold
0         16   1          1     100
1         25   4          4      81
2         36   9         21      64
3         49  12         16      49
4         64  25         25      36
```

This is the code to generate it:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
data = {'Col1': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'Col2': [1, 2, 3, 3, 5], 'Col3': [1, 2, 7, 4, 5], 'Col4': [10, 9, 8, 7, 6]}
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Monday_One', 'Water', 'Cold'), ('Monday_One', 'Water', 'Hot'),
                                 ('Monday_Two', 'Water', 'Hot'), ('Tuesday', 'Ice', 'Cold')])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1.columns = col

data = {'Col1': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'Col2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Col3': [10, 9, 8, 7, 6]}
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Area', 'Water', 'Cold'), ('Area', 'Water', 'Hot'),
                                 ('Area', 'Ice', 'Cold')])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2.columns = col

data = {'Col1': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('One', 'One', 'One')])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df3.columns = col

df3[('Monday_One', 'Water', 'Cold')] = df1[('Monday_One', 'Water', 'Cold')] * df2[('Area', 'Water', 'Cold')]
df3[('Monday_One', 'Water', 'Hot')] = df1[('Monday_One', 'Water', 'Hot')] * df2[('Area', 'Water', 'Hot')]
df3[('Monday_Two', 'Water', 'Hot')] = df1[('Monday_Two', 'Water', 'Hot')] * df2[('Area', 'Water', 'Hot')]
df3[('Tuesday', 'Ice', 'Cold')] = df1[('Tuesday', 'Ice', 'Cold')] * df2[('Area', 'Ice', 'Cold')]

df3 = df3.drop(df3.columns[0], axis=1)
```

The goal is to multiply every column in df1 with the respective column in df2, ignoring the first level of the multiindex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for set `MultiIndex` names, so possible align DataFrames by [`DataFrame.align`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.align.html) with remove first level of `df2` and then multiple:

```
df2 = df2.rename_axis(('a','b','c'), axis=1)
df1 = df1.rename_axis(('a','b','c'), axis=1)

df5, df6 = df2.droplevel(0, axis=1).align(df1)
print (df5)
b     Ice      Water                      
c    Cold       Cold        Hot           
a Tuesday Monday_One Monday_One Monday_Two
0      10          4          1          1
1       9          5          2          2
2       8          6          3          3
3       7          7          4          4
4       6          8          5          5


df = df1.mul(df5)
print (df)
a Monday_One     Monday_Two Tuesday
b      Water          Water     Ice
c       Cold Hot        Hot    Cold
0         16   1          1     100
1         25   4          4      81
2         36   9         21      64
3         49  12         16      49
4         64  25         25      36
```

Another idea with `multiple` with set columns names, for original order is added [`DataFrame.reorder_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df2 = df2.rename_axis(('a','b','c'), axis=1)
df1 = df1.rename_axis(('a','b','c'), axis=1)


df = (df1.mul(df2.droplevel(0, axis=1))
         .reorder_levels(['a','b','c'], axis=1)
         .reindex(df1.columns, axis=1))
print (df)
a Monday_One     Monday_Two Tuesday
b      Water          Water     Ice
c       Cold Hot        Hot    Cold
0         16   1          1     100
1         25   4          4      81
2         36   9         21      64
3         49  12         16      49
4         64  25         25      36
```

Comment: The first solution is returning the following error in PyCharm Debugger: Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135) so I cannot confirm it but the second solution looks to be working. I will validate it with my "real" dataframes first and will accept the answer after. Thanks

Comment: I didn't realise you can do that kind of align! awesome

Comment: @Thanasis - One idea possible problem - if remove first level from `df2` then is `MultiIndex` values unique?

Comment: @Thanasis - For test `df2.droplevel(0, axis=1).columns.is_unique`

Comment: @jezrael Yes they will always be unique and returning True to the test

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to find the commonalities between the two dataframe columns, multiply them and create a new dataframe with the result:

```
outcome = {ent: df1[ent] * df2.loc(axis=1)[entry].to_numpy() 
           for ent in df1.columns 
           for entry in df2.columns 
           if ent[1:] == entry[1:]})

pd.DataFrame(outcome) 

  Monday_One     Monday_Two Tuesday
       Water          Water     Ice
        Cold Hot        Hot    Cold
0         16   1          1     100
1         25   4          4      81
2         36   9         21      64
3         49  12         16      49
4         64  25         25      36
```

Another option, which also uses a pairing to get the right combinations before multiplying and concatenation - note that this second option is slower than the first option, especially as the size of the data increases:

```
ix = pd.IndexSlice
slicers = [ix[:, "Water", "Hot"], 
           ix[:, "Water", "Cold"], 
           ix[:, "Ice", "Cold"]]

left = [df1.loc[:, entry] 
        for entry in slicers]

right = [df2.loc[:, entry].to_numpy() 
         for entry in slicers]

pd.concat([l * r for l, r in zip(left, right)], axis = 1)

  Monday_One Monday_Two Monday_One Tuesday
       Water      Water      Water     Ice
         Hot        Hot       Cold    Cold
0          1          1         16     100
1          4          4         25      81
2          9         21         36      64
3         12         16         49      49
4         25         25         64      36
```